# Images upload form laravel

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4

My image upload doesn't work:

Controller:

```
if (Input::hasFile('image')) {
        $bikecreate->image = Input::file('image');
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/upload/';
        $filename = str_random(6) . '_' . $bikecreate->users_id ;
        Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    }
```

Form:

```
{{ Form::file('image', array('files' => true)) }}
```

After accepting form everything looks ok, but after the end of upload, filepath in database show .tmp/file at my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to see exactly what's going on but my guess is that your line `$bikecreate->image = Input::file('image')` is where you're setting the file's path for the database. You've actually set the `UploadedFile` instance as the `image` property on `$bikecreate` there, which, presumably, when serialised to something to put into the database gets `__toString()` called on it.

`__toString()` called on a `File` instance (which itself inherits `__toString` from SPLFileInfo returns the path to that file. So you'd think you're get the uploaded filename, but actually because an uploaded file is actually a temporary file in PHP, you get the temporary name.

Try changing that line to the following:

```
$bikecreate->image = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

This retrieves the actual original name of the uploaded file, not the temporary path given to it by PHP.

It goes without saying that this is only pertinent to `UploadedFile`s, normal files should just be able to be `__toString`ed to get the path to the file, although you'll notice that it would be the full path and not the basename. To get that, use `getBaseName()`.